# Would it be "Life was" or "Life were" in this Circumstance?

Tags: word-choice, grammar, phrase-requests, american-english, sentence

This may be a correct vs. more correct situation.

“If life was simple, we’d never grow.”

I wonder if this should be "were" or "was." "Were" is used for unreal conditionals, so when looking up “if life…” then “were” normally shows up. But I wonder if “was” would actually be correct here because life being simple is a possibility for some and not for others, so there’s duality to the meaning. It could be simple for some and complex for others.

Comment: There is a wealth of information in the previous answers to the questions of which this is a duplicate.